# Angularjs How can i post/put/delete data into local json file?

Tags: angularjs, json, file, post, put

Angularjs How can i post/put data into local json file?

To get data, i do:

```
App.factory('serv', ['$http', function ($http) {
  var data = {};
  db.getdata = function(){
    return $http.get('data/album.json');
  }
  return data;
}])
```

I dont know how to do for POST , PUT and DELETE.

Is it possible?

Comment: *"Is it possible"* ... you can't post to a static resource file. Only a dynamic programming language on server can manipulate a file

Comment: You could use local storage/IndexedDB to emulate it.

Comment: Thanks for the good question, me also facing the same issue and I could not find answer. Did you find any solution which does not inlcude additional APIs? if yes, then could you write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this useful Angular API : https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

if you want to manage data saved in a json file then you can use  this JSON server : https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Answer (score 0):

You can write to local files with JavaScript using the HTML5 file system API. Check here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem to see if it's supported where you need to use it.

If you are able to use it, then you would simply write out a new JSON file in its entirety when you want to persist your data. You can read about the file system API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Introduction

If your needs are more than just a simple JSON document you might want to check out indexeddb as well.